# Accessing jar file libraries at runtime

Tags: java, jar, loading

In my code, near the top of one of the source files is this line:

```
import com.google.code.chatterboxapi.ChatterBox;
```

This is an external jar library, and when I ran my code, which I build into a Jar file, in the command line outside the IDE I was using, Java complained that it couldn't find com.google.code.chatterboxapi.ChatterBox. How do I tell the JVM where to find the jar where the libraries are?

Answer (score 3):

You use the `classpath` option of java

```
-cp <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
-classpath <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
              A : separated list of directories, JAR archives,
              and ZIP archives to search for class files.
```